# Cannot read property of undefined jasmine test

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have written a test in jasmine for my angular application which is failing but the actual functionality works absolutely fine. I am also calling the fixture.DetectChanges() but not sure what the problem could be. I am getting an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'maxSize' of undefined at DomicileSelectionComponent.isMinValid (webpack:///C:/vstsprojects/Risk.Analytics.Captives/Clientside/captives/src/app/pages/feasibility/ca
>   ptives/domicile-selection/domicile-selection.component.ts?:88:52)

Why is the error coming for only maxSize and not minSize ?

TestComponent

```
describe('DomicileSelectionComponent', () => {
  let comp: DomicileSelectionComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DomicileSelectionComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        TooltipModule.forRoot(),
        FormsModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: { provide: TranslateLoader, useClass: TranslateFakeLoader }
        })
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: BsModalRef, useClass: BsModalRefStub },
        { provide: BackendProxy.ReferenceProxy, useClass: ReferenceProxyStub },
        { provide: RunService, useValue: runServiceStub }
      ],
      declarations: [DomicileSelectionComponent, YesNoPipe, CLICK_INPUT_DIRECTIVE, ShortNumberFormatPipe]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
   spyOn(BsModalRefStub.prototype, 'hide').and.callThrough();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DomicileSelectionComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    comp.domicileInfo = domicileInformationDataResult.data;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  fit('should return true because the index of the item is zero and min is less than max', () => {
    comp.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items = [{  minSize: 30000000, maxSize: 40000000, values: [0.02, 0.02]}];
    fixture.detectChanges();
    console.log(comp.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items);
    let isMin: boolean = comp.isMinValid(comp.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items, 0);
    expect(isMin).toBe(true);
  });

});
```

Main component

```
isMinValid(currentItem: any, index: number) {
    if (index === 0 && (+currentItem.minSize <= +currentItem.maxSize)) {
        return !this._isMinValid;
    }
    else if ( index === 0 && +currentItem.minSize >= +currentItem.maxSize) {
          return this._isMinValid;
    } 
    let previousItem = this.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items[index - 1];
    if (+currentItem.minSize !== +previousItem.maxSize) {
     return this._isMinValid;
    }
    return !this._isMinValid;
  }
```

Comment: Is it normal that you give the entire array on `comp.isMinValid(comp.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items, 0);` ?

Comment: it should have only one item in the array

Comment: I got my answer. I just passed a single array item and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is there :

```
fit('should return true because the index of the item is zero and min is less than max', () => {
    comp.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items = [{  minSize: 30000000, maxSize: 40000000, values: [0.02, 0.02]}];
    fixture.detectChanges();
    console.log(comp.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items);
    let isMin: boolean = comp.isMinValid(comp.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items, 0);
    expect(isMin).toBe(true);
});
```

You give to isMinValid the entire array ( `comp.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items`. )

Try this :

```
let isMin: boolean = comp.isMinValid(comp.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items[0], 0);
```